# ASP.NET Core multi-provider authentication for mobile apps

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, mobile-application

I've seen that Azure App Service mobile apps can implement [authentication for multiple identity providers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/) via a single client SDK.  If an app hosted on Azure App Service is using ASP.NET Core in the cloud, though, can its UWP or Windows Store client app also benefit from multiple identity providers via a single client SDK?

- If yes, then how does that work?  Does it use the same mobile client SDK?
- If no, then how would I authenticate such a mobile client?  Will I have to use individual provider SDKs?

I know ASP.NET Core is still prerelease, but I'm wondering:

1. What multi-provider authentication functionality is available from a mobile client now?
2. What such functionality is planned to be available when ASP.NET Core 1.0 is finally released?
3. What such functionality will likely be on the roadmap for the future?

Answer (score 4):

Azure App Service provides authentication as a service.  In other words, the client authenticates to the service, and the service passes on the authentication to you.

Underneath, the app service passes a number of authentication related app settings within environment variables that you can read via the normal method.  The original JWT is also passed in via the X-ZUMO-AUTH header.

For your clients, probably the best way is to use the Azure Mobile Apps client SDKs - there are clients for .NET (Xamarin, UWP), JavaScript, iOS and Android.  You don't need the data access functionality - just the client creation and login / loginAsync method calls.

For your server, take a look at the [Authentication Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/) for more information.  You may also want to read some of the info in [Chris Gillums blog](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/) for more technically details.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the scenario works.  Which .NET framework will my ASP.NET Core server code be running on in the cloud?  The full .NET 4.6, just .NET Core, or is it up to me to decide?

Comment: It's up to you to decide.  The full Azure Mobile Apps SDK uses ASP.NET 4.6 - .NET Core 1.0 RC2 is a choice as well.